# How to do groupby.nunique and keep names of values counted?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
name   type    value
a     first     10a
a     first     7b
a     second    9c
b     first     5r
b     first     7r
b     first     9r
```

if i do `df.groupby(["name", "type"]).nunique()` i will get:

```
name   type    value
a     first     2
a     second    1
b     first     3
```

How could i keep names of values in other columns? I want to get:

```
name   type    value  value_name
a     first     2      [10a, 7b]
a     second    1      [9c]
b     first     3      [5r, 7r, 9r]
```

How could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
new_df = df.groupby(["name", "type"]).agg(value=('value','nunique'),value_name=('value', 'unique'))
```

**Output**:

```
             value    value_name
name type                       
a    first       2     [10a, 7b]
     second      1          [9c]
b    first       3  [5r, 7r, 9r]
```

use **reset_index()** for the expected output:

```
new_df = new_df.reset_index()
'''
  name    type  value    value_name
0    a   first      2     [10a, 7b]
1    a  second      1          [9c]
2    b   first      3  [5r, 7r, 9r]
'''
```